# Video src won't reload on click of a different object

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, click, html5-video

I recently asked a similar question regarding audio posts... but I've had a more difficult time with videos. For reference, I've provided a link to the (working) audio example as well as a link to the (broken) video example.

http://www.eastcoastband.com/new/audio-clip/

http://www.eastcoastband.com/new/video-gallery/

As you can see, the audio clips always replace and reload on click, but the videos only replace and reload on the first click. I'll provide some code below..

HTML:

```
<video id="video-play" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKvtOAzO_-o" type="video/youtube" controls autoplay >
<h5 
class="change-video" 
data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKvtOAzO_-o" 
data-version="video/youtube">

<img width="480" height="360" src="http://www.eastcoastband.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/wedding-band-or-dj-oh-the-dilemm.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Wedding Band or DJ?  Oh, the Dilemma">
</h5>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.change-video').click(function(){
  var src = $(this).data('video');
  var type = $(this).data('version');
  var player = MediaElementPlayer('#video-play');

  player.pause();
  player.setSrc(src);
  $('#video-play').attr('type', type);
  player.load();
  player.play();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it says that type is not defined, where are you getting "type" from?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.change-video').click(function(){
  var src = $(this).data('video');
  var type = $(this).data('version');
  var player = MediaElementPlayer('#video-play');

  player.pause();
  player.setSrc(src);
//  $('#video-play').attr('type', type);
  player.load();
  player.play();
});
```

type is either out of scope or undefined

Comment: Hey Evan I had tried using that prior to submitting the question to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: it says that type is not defined, where are you getting "type" from?

Comment: if you remove this line: $('#video-play').attr('type').attr('autoload','none'); it works though

Comment: I apologize for my mistype! The second var src should read var type. It allows room for me to retype the video if the uploaded file is an mp4.

Comment: the problem is on line 8 the variable type is not defined

Comment: if you comment out that line, it will work. where are you getting the variable "type" from?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: $('#video-play').attr('type', ----->type); you are referencing type as a variable, where do you define type in your code

Comment: As far as I can tell, the script simply isn't re-running itself after the first click event, and I don't know how to tell it to do so. I've defined type as a variable in the script immediately after defining src.

Comment: comment out line 8 and tell me if it starts working, as far as i see (I tested it on the page you linked to), it should. it isn't working because you are setting the type attribute of that HtmlElement to the value of the variable type which does not exist, if you post your full code I should be able to help you pinpoint where exactly the problem is in your code

Comment: I've attempted this, and it makes no difference as the variable type is defined.

Comment: hmm, I see. ok, give me a few minutes

Comment: honestly, I am stumped. perhaps it is an issue with the API that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no type="video/youtube" for MIME Types for Video Formats. You can find reference in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

```
Format    MIME-type
MP4       video/mp4
WebM      video/webm
Ogg       video/ogg
```

Comment: I've added video/youtube to my htaccess to permit this type. It is required in order to play youtube videos. I've provided a reference link for the original script below:

http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube